# Meaning of おく in this sentence

Tags: meaning, words

> 目の不自由な方のものです。モノをおかないで!

The best translation I could come up for this is "It is your blind spot. Don't ignore it!"
おかないで confused me a bit. I don't know if it's 置く or 措く, but I also see that both forms can mean "to leave behind/exclude", which is why I thought that the phrase is referring to not paying attention to your blind spot. Is this accurate?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> 「目{め}の不自由{ふじゆう}な方{かた}のものです。モノをおかないで!」

おかないで ＝ 置かないで　＝ "please don't place"

This is a sign occasionally seen near the Braille blocks for the blind in public places -- in particular, on the sidewalks.

「目の不自由な方」 means "the blind".

> "This (= The Braille) is for the blind.  Please do not put (and leave) things here (on the Braille blocks)!"

Not sure where you get "blind spot" from.  「方」 means "persons" here.

「もの」 in the first sentence describes "intangible possession".  The Braille blocks "exist" for the blind.  A sensible orthography choice indeed.

「モノ」 in the second refers to the tangible items such as luggage, boxes, etc. that people might possibly leave on the Braille blocks.  They could have used the kanji 「物」 for this one but went with the lighter-looking katakana.

Comment: I was reading 方 as ほう for some reason, and not かた. I saw it as "the blind side/direction" instead of "the blind person", which makes way more sense.

Comment: Yep. 方 in this case is an honorific/polite way to refer to a person/people; in normal speech you might see it as 目の不自由な人 instead.